# Can I compile Multiple classes into one program with CodeDom?

Tags: c#, codedom

Now this has been bugging me for ages and it's time to find out if it's possible. I currently have a working CodeDom that can compile one class, but I have created a program with multiple classes that I want to compile with CodeDom. I've tried looking here:
[CodeDom - Linking multiple classes within a single Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753606/codedom-linking-multiple-classes-within-a-single-assembly)
^ No help...
and here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.aspx
^ Not much help...

So, is this possible? And if so, how specifically do I do it? How can I link my classes together and compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of the CodeDOM tree, there is `CodeCompileUnit`, which is roughly equivalent to a single C# source code file. When you use `CompileAssemblyFromDom()` to compile, it actually takes a collection of `CodeCompileUnit`s. This means you can easily compile multiple classes at once: just create a separate `CodeCompileUnit` for each of them.

But that's not the only option, `CodeCompileUnit` (just like a C# file) can contain multiple class declarations (indirectly through `CodeNamespace`), so you could use that instead.